# Why does AcquireToken with ClientCredential fail with invalid_client (ACS50012)?

Tags: azure, oauth, .net-4.0, azure-active-directory, adal

Why won't my Azure AD application allow an oauth client_credentials grant?

I want to use the Azure Graph API, but first I need an oauth token. To get the token, I am trying to use Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory aka ADAL version 1.0.3 (from NuGet).

I'm using the overload of AuthenticationContext.AcquireToken that takes a ClientCredential object. (I can't use the overload that prompts the user to login because I'm writing a service, not an app.)

I configured my Azure AD web application as described in various tutorials/samples (e.g. [ADAL - Server to Server Authentication](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/AAL-Server-to-Server-9aafccc1)).

My code looks like:

```
AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/thommmondago.onmicrosoft.com");
ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential("41151135-61b8-40f4-aff7-8627e9eaf853", clientSecretKey);
AuthenticationResult result = ac.AcquireToken("https://graph.windows.net", cc);
```

The `AcquireToken` line throws an exception:

```
sts_token_request_failed: Token request to security token service failed.  Check InnerException for more details
```

The inner exception is a WebException, and the response received looks like an oauth error:

```
{ "error":"invalid_client",
 "error_description":"ACS50012: Authentication failed."
 "error_codes":[50012],
 "timestamp":"2014-03-17 12:26:19Z",
 "trace_id":"a4ee6702-e07b-40f7-8248-589e49e96a8d",
 "correlation_id":"b304af2e-2748-4067-99d0-2d7e55b121cd" }
```

Bypassing ADAL and using curl with the oauth endpoint also gives the same error.

My code works if I use the details of the Azure application that I found [here](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/AzureAD-Node-Sample/wiki/Windows-Azure-Active-Directory-Graph-API-Access-Using-OAuth-2.0):

```
AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/graphDir1.onmicrosoft.com");
ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential("b3b1fc59-84b8-4400-a715-ea8a7e40f4fe", "FStnXT1QON84B5o38aEmFdlNhEnYtzJ91Gg/JH/Jxiw=");
AuthenticationResult result = ac.AcquireToken("https://graph.windows.net", cc);
```

So it's not an error with my code. I think it's either an error with my Azure AD, or I've got the ClientCredential parameters wrong.

Comment: If your code works with the sample credentials, it sounds like an issue with your configuration.  Have you set your domain in the azure management portal, under APP ID URI?   That must match your "resource" param.  Also re-check your client secret.

Comment: The resource I want a token for is the Graph API, so I set the APP ID URI to the graph endpoint (from View Endpoints button) and used that in the resource param. Also generated a new secret key. Same result.

Comment: Can you try https: //graph.windows.net
as the APP ID URI?  That's what I use for the same scenario.  (Sorry had to put a space in the url to keep it from autoformatting)

Comment: Thanks for your effort to help, it was an Azure issue in the end. FYI I couldn't set APP ID URI to https: //graph.windows.net, Azure prevented it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This turned out to be an error in Windows Azure, there was nothing wrong with my code or config.

After Microsoft fixed the problem in Azure, I had to create a new application and it started working.

[Forum answer from Microsoft:](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/864228cd-6326-4c59-8e30-f24e4cb37fcc/adal-acquiretoken-with-clientcredential-fails-with-invalidclient-acs50012?forum=WindowsAzureAD)

> ```
> Hi,
> ```
>
> We are seeing some errors with applications created in a several day time range, ending yesterday. We are continuing to fix up these applications but I don't have a good eta when this will be done. I'm apologize for the impact here.
>
> Can you try creating a new application and retying the operation with the new client id?
>
> thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue but only running the code directly from Azure (inside an Azure Website).

I solved upgrading 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory' package to '2.6.1-alpha'

Comment: I created a project using default template as described in http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/developing-aspnet-apps-with-windows-azure-active-directory in VS-2013 community edition. It was referencing to version 1.0.0 of 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Client.ActiveDirectory'. Updated it to the latest version (2.12.111071459) using nuget. Everything worked fine :-))

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/resource-manager-net-sdk/

The latest version of Active Directory Authentication Library does not support AcquireToken method, instead you have to use AcquireTokenAsync method.

```
var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource: "https://{domain}.onmicrosoft.com/{site-if applicable}", clientCredential: credential);
```

Comment: Link to doc is broken

Answer (score 0):

The azure version of the translator has changed things once more- the Oauth token request uses a new url and only needs your secret key, instead of all the other baggage. This page discusses it (but using PHP code): http://www.bradymoritz.com/php-code-for-bingmicrosoftazure-translator/

The key items are:

1. Post an empty request to  https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken
2. Pass it your secret key using the header "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: "
3. Or, just use the querystring parameter: "Subscription-Key="

Then get the body of the return as the actual token- it's the whole body, not in json format.

This is a lot simpler than the method used before, but it'd definitely a pain that things have yet again changed.